# Is this the new place for the Qt SDK?

Tags: qt

I'm seeing this link being referenced a lot for the Qt SDK, but it's been dead for quite some time now: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Is [this](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/) the "new" place for the Qt SDK?

Comment: Nokia has not controlled the QT Framework for over 2 years.  There is only one download, everything you need, is on the QT Framework website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go up two levels, you can access later versions.

http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

If you go all the way up, you'll see official_releases.

https://download.qt.io/

Comment: Ah, yes - I was looking for the latest 4.8 one so that's why... but so this is in fact the Qt SDK then?

Comment: It appears to be.  However, I cannot find anything online for why SDK is no longer in the title.